# iOS Localized in the single project through the Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

when I use the `NSLocalizedString` to localize the app, I create a new strings named `Localizable`. It worked firstly through the localize and adding the languages.

However, when I delete the `Localizable.strings` and recreate the strings, there is a problem that can not localize, system can not find the strings and can add language such as `zh_hans`, `english` and so on.

**See below image for more detail.**

[image: Screen shot]